# how long should it take to create a raid 10 with 4 3TB disks?

Tags: mdadm

I am trying to create a raid 10 with four 3TB disks on ubuntu 12.10 with mdadm. I was wondering how long should it take to create the raid. Right now when I look at /proc/mdstat it is showing 19107 minutes. That is more than 13 days. Is this normal?

Are there any tools that can achieve the same result faster?

My boot drive is different from the disks in the enclosure. I am using mac mini 6,1 with ubuntu 12.10 and external USB 3.0 raid enclosure. I have Western Digital 3TB disks.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you creating a RAID 10 array? Shouldn't it be a RAID 4 array? I could be mistaken on RAID but i'm pretty sure you are supposed to be using RAID 4.

Comment: No. RAID 10 is correct. The number after RAID does not indicate the number of drives used, but how they are used. With 4 large drives using RAID 10 is a sane choice.  (For more details on RAID and a long explanation see this post on our sister site: http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them )

Comment: I am trying to do a strip of mirrors for redundancy. The process is still going now the /proc/mdstat shows 3655 minutes. I guess I will wait for the process to complete.

Comment: Ok, It took about 4 days but it did complete.